# Javascript : Embed a string in javascript code

Tags: javascript, html

I am getting images in a loop and in loop I am making a html string, now within loop based on condition I want to add few attributes to specific images, that's not working properly for me, please help .

```
for(var i = 1; i <= 17; i++) {
        //var ind = parseInt(i / 4);
        var ind = i;
        if(ind==1){
            var step = " data-step=\'4\'  data-show=\'sports\'data-intro=\'community\'" ; 
        }
        else if(ind==2 ){
            var step = " data-step=\'5\'  data-show=\'sports\'data-intro=\'community\'" ; 
        }
        else {
            setp ='';

        }

        html +='<img  src="'+baseurl+'front/images/layers/small/'+i+'.png"    class="img-block cur" id="img-block-'+i+'" data-ls=\'{"index":'+ind+',"width":"'+arrWidthSizes(i)+'"}\' onclick="LoadDemoPopup_create('+i+')"   />';


}
```

How do I add this `step` within image tag?

Maybe a silly question but I am stuck with this.

Comment: Just add it in the same way you're adding in the `baseurl` variable etc. Also spell "step" correctly everywhere.

Comment: You don't need to escape `'` inside `""`. You only need to escape quotes if they're the same type that you're using to delimit the string.